# Locating Symmetry Equivalent Atoms from Distance Matrix?

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, python, symmetry, hartree-fock

As a follow up to my previous question [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-use-libint-with-python), I am now trying to implement symmetry detection in my code. I am following the paper by [Beruski et. al](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.23493) to understand the background required. I am able to find the Principal Axes of Inertia and the Moments of Intertia using the following code

```py
import  numpy           as  np
import  math            as  mt
import  numpy.linalg    as  linalg

def translateCoordinates(coords: np.ndarray, mass: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    com =   np.sum(np.transpose(coords) * mass, axis=1)/ np.sum(mass)
    translated  =   []
    for coord in coords:
        translated.append(np.subtract(coord, com))
    translated  =   np.array(translated)
    return translated

def generateIntertiaTensor(coords: np.ndarray, mass: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    inertiatensor    =   np.zeros((3,3))
    for coord, mass in zip(coords, mass):
        inertiatensor[0][0] =   inertiatensor[0][0] +    mass * pow(coord[1], 2) + mass * pow(coord[2], 2)
        inertiatensor[1][1] =   inertiatensor[1][1] +    mass * pow(coord[0], 2) + mass * pow(coord[2], 2)
        inertiatensor[2][2] =   inertiatensor[2][2] +    mass * pow(coord[1], 2) + mass * pow(coord[0], 2)

        inertiatensor[1][0] =   inertiatensor[1][0] +   -1 * mass * coord[0] * coord[1]
        inertiatensor[2][0] =   inertiatensor[2][0] +   -1 * mass * coord[0] * coord[2]
        inertiatensor[1][2] =   inertiatensor[1][2] +   -1 * mass * coord[1] * coord[2]

    inertiatensor[0][1]  =   inertiatensor[1][0]
    inertiatensor[0][2]  =   inertiatensor[2][0]
    inertiatensor[2][1]  =   inertiatensor[1][2]

    moments, axes   =   linalg.eigh(inertiatensor)
    axes            =   np.transpose(axes)
    
    # gram-schmidt orthogonalization
    orthogonalaxes      =   np.zeros((3,3))
    orthogonalaxes[:,0] =   axes[:,0]
    orthogonalaxes[:,1] =   axes[:,1] - (np.dot(axes[:,0], axes[:,1])/np.dot(axes[:,0], axes[:,0]))*axes[:,0]
    orthogonalaxes[:,2] =   axes[:,2] - (np.dot(axes[:,0], axes[:,2])/np.dot(axes[:,0], axes[:,0]))*axes[:,0] - (np.dot(orthogonalaxes[:,1], axes[:,2])/np.dot(orthogonalaxes[:,1], orthogonalaxes[:,1]))*orthogonalaxes[:,1]
    
    orthogonalaxes[:,0] =   orthogonalaxes[:,0] / np.linalg.norm(orthogonalaxes[:,0])
    orthogonalaxes[:,1] =   orthogonalaxes[:,1] / np.linalg.norm(orthogonalaxes[:,1])
    orthogonalaxes[:,2] =   orthogonalaxes[:,2] / np.linalg.norm(orthogonalaxes[:,2])

    return orthogonalaxes

def printAxes(axes: np.ndarray) -> None:
    for vec in axes:
        print("{:10.3f}{:10.3f}{:10.3f}".format(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]))

def printCoords(coords: np.ndarray) -> None:
    for coord in coords:
        print("{:10.3f}{:10.3f}{:10.3f}".format(coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]))

def printDistanceMatrix(distancematrix: np.ndarray) -> None:
    for row in distancematrix:
        print(row)

def generateDistanceMatrix(coords: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    natoms  =   coords.shape[0]
    distancematrix  =   np.zeros((natoms, natoms))
    for index_i, coord_i in enumerate(coords):
        for index_j, coord_j in enumerate(coords):
            distancematrix[index_i][index_j]    =   round(mt.sqrt(np.dot(coord_i-coord_j, coord_i-coord_j)),3)

    unique, count = np.unique(distancematrix, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    repeated_groups = unique[count > 1]
    print(unique)

#    for repeated_group in repeated_groups:
#        repeated_idx = np.argwhere(np.all(distancematrix == repeated_group, axis=1))
#        print(repeated_idx.ravel())
    return distancematrix

def readCoords(filename: str) -> np.ndarray:
    coords  =   []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line    =   line.split()
            tcoord  =   [float(x) for x in line[1:]]
            coords.append(tcoord)
    coords  =   np.array(coords)
    return coords

coords  =   readCoords("methane.dat")
mass    =   [12.004, 1.008, 1.008, 1.008, 1.008]
distancematrix  =   generateDistanceMatrix(coords)
printDistanceMatrix(distancematrix)
```

However, I am stuck at finding the symmetry equivalent atoms from the distance matrix. A brute force comparision would be *O(N$^2$)*, and would soon become very expensive even for moderately sized molecules. Is there a better way to do it?

**Edited to add Further Information:**

I got around the detection of point group of the molecule using openbabel package in python and C++. However, this came at the cost of needing to create a OBMol object just for symmetry detection and coordinate reorientation. I am still interested in a naive but somewhat optimal way (which can be implemented in C++ or python) to identify the symmetry equivalent atoms, without the need to create extra objects.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! Do you speak ગુજરાતી? I happen to be Gujarati :)

Comment: If you want symmetry unique atoms, I'd highly suggest using the open-source [libmsym](https://github.com/mcodev31/libmsym) which has Python and C/C++ interfaces. It's reliable (i.e., we use it in Avogadro2) and almost certainly provides whatever you want. The publication is ["Automatic procedure for generating symmetry adapted wavefunctions"](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13321-017-0193-3)

Comment: @NikeDattani, I do not speak Gujarati, however I can understand it. I just moved here for my PhD :)

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230376/symmetry-unique-atom-coordinates
Related. 
Perhaps this helps.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this question? Please update us if you found something! Are you still seeking the answer?

Comment: Prof. Dattani, I am still looking for the answer. The link Vandan had given did give some ideas, but was not applicable in my case.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to extract this information from the distance matrix? Aren't the atom coordinates the natural starting point for this? If that would also be an acceptable starting point for you, I could point you to the related subroutine of the open-source code (for solids) I am involved in, where we solve this issue in O(n), if I remember correctly.

Comment: @GregorMichalicek Can you please join [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112358/python-based-matter-modeling-software)? I will try explaining the motivation.

Comment: @Hemanth Haridas: I just read your question again and found that I somehow got it wrong the first time I read it. I now think I cannot really contribute substantially to a solution. Sorry. What may be a useful hint is that the density of the atoms is not infinite. This means if you search for certain atoms in a specific region in space, you can in a preprocessing step put the atoms in bins for local regions. Maybe this removes one of your loops.

Comment: While I see that you're using `openbabel` to do symmetry detection, the underlying implementation is really brute force. I'll repeat my suggestion to use `libmsym` above, which has both C++ and Python bindings and is far, far better.

Comment: Did you get this answered? I see no response to the last two comments by Gregor and Geoff!

Comment: I am using libmsym do it now.

Comment: It seems that your question is this: "Is there a better way to do it?" It seems that your answer is: "use libmsym". Is that correct? If so, perhaps you can write an answer?